# how to get validator fail response in key value pair in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am making register API in laravel.
I have used Validator to validate the form.

Below is the my controller:

```
 public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'contact' => 'required|numeric|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|regex:/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$/|confirmed',
    ],
    [
        'contact.unique' => 'The phone number is already in use.',
        'email.unique' => 'The email address is already in use.',
        'password.regex' => 'Password should be a minimum of 8 characters including uppercase and lowercase letters, at least 1 number and at least 1 special character (!@#$%^&*).',
        'password.confirmed' => 'Password does not match.',
    ]
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['user' => 'Failed', 'message' => $validator->errors()], 409);
    }
}
```

It gives response in postman:

```
{
"user": "Failed",
"message": {
    "contact": [
        "The phone number is already in use."
    ],
    "email": [
        "The email address is already in use."
    ]
}
}
```

But I need like this:

```
{
"user": "Failed",
"message": "The email address is already in use and The phone number is already in use."
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$message = count($validator->errors()->all()) > 1 ? implode($validator->errors()->all(), ' and ').'.' : $validator->errors()->all()[0].'.';

return response()->json(['user' => 'Failed', 'message' => $message], 409);
```

You need to remove the dot from your custom validation messages (and append it on your concatenated message as seen above (`$message`).